# Separating the instrument and vocals from an MP3 in Objective C

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, core-audio

I'm trying to take out the instrumentals in any mp3 in objective-c for a karaoke song maker. The solution doesn't have to be perfect. I think the general idea from my research is it should be some sort of filter that leaves the vocals intact but affects the range of frequencies that are instruments. I don't have much of a background in signal processing but would love some help on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

In general, separating instrumentals and vocals can't be done by filtering, as the audio spectrum frequency range of vocals and instrumentals overlap quite a bit.

For stereo music where the main vocal is panned dead-center, and with the instrumental music panned off to one side or the other, one can remove some of the vocals in the mix by subtracting one channel from the other (say the left from the right).  To do this subtraction, you would have to convert the mp3 into uncompressed audio of raw PCM samples, and work with C data types.

A search term for academic research on how this might be accomplished is "blind source separation".

Comment: I guess there is no easy solution to this. My follow up would be how much interference will the instrumentals have on an frequency detection for the vocals? I'm doing a fft on the samples and it gives me very spiky results. Is there a way to filter out the "known instrumental frequencies" so that I get better results?

Comment: Instrumental frequencies usually cover a wider range than do vocals.  There may be research papers on "blind source separation", but the process is vastly more complicated than just filtering.